# MVVM Service method Design

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Basically I have my methods in my service setup like: `void GetWebsites(Action<IEnumerable<Site>, Exception> callback);`.

Right now my services run locally and are just implementations of the interface. We are however planning on moving to WCF at a later date. My question is is this acceptable or should I do this a different way.

I'd like to be able to support running my methods on a Task and sending progress updates back to the view model that called the service so it can display a progress bar or something.

I was thinking that I should maybe replace the Action with an IObservable and just subscribe to it in my ViewModel that way I can communicate Asynchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [duplex service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx) will let your service report back to your client asynchronously. Make a one-way call to "GetWebSites" on your service. Then your service can start pushing Sites back to your view model as it sees fit.